# Как оформить запрос на декодирование?

Tags: python

Есть программа на python, она должна брать картинку .png и доставать информацию из неё, а далее записывать инфо в отдельный .xml файл. В программе есть пример, но по моему запросу

```
prov.py ('D://a.png')
```

выдает

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
prov.py ('D://a.png')
NameError: name 'prov' is not defined
```

Прошу меня простить, в питоне не разбираюсь, помогите, пожалуйста. [Вот ссылка на исходный код](http://pastebin.com/SXBBZqJ8).

Comment: Так скрипты не запускаются. Ищите в поиске «Как запустить скрипт питона».

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, вы не туда его отправили )

@Ilya Chicago, это вам не octave, надо гуглить, как сделать импорт другого файла, и уже из импортированного файла вызывать нужную функцию.

Comment: Запрос на декодировани**е**  
доставать информацию из **неё**

Comment: @BOPOH, можно и без импорта:  

    import sys
    sys.argv = [ 'D://a.png' ]
    execfile( 'prov.py' )

Comment: @ReinRaus, Что я сделал неправильно?
    
    execfile( 'prov.py' )
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
        execfile( 'prov.py' )
    NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
____
@ReinRaus, я посмотрел, у меня python 3.4, а там этот оператор заменён на exec, я вот только не могу разобраться, как его использовать.
____

@ReinRaus, я заменил execfile на exec, как должен выглядит дальнейший запрос? Правильно ли я переделал execfile?
import sys
sys.argv = [ 'D://a.png' ]
exec(open ( 'prov.py' ).read())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prov.py` -- это скрипт, который надо запускать с командной строки, а не из pyshell. Этот файл не рассчитан, что его будут импортировать как обычный Питон модуль, т.е. `import prov` пытается выполнить код, который обычно исполняется только внутри `if __name__ == "__main__"` блока.

Скрипт содержит примеры, как его использовать из консоли:

```
%prog a.png                      # decode a.png to a.png.xml
%prog *.png                      # decode creatures in all png images
%prog -m --name Emu Owl.png      # change creature name in Owl.png to "Emu"
%prog -e -i b.jpg c.xml -o a.png # encode c.xml in image b.jpg, write to a.png
%prog -l creature.png            # display name, creator, ... of creature.png
```

В cmd.exe:

```
C:\> py prov.py D:\a.png
```

Если хочется вызвать `prov.py` из другого Питон-скрипта, то это можно сделать, как с любой другой программой:

```
import sys
from subprocess import check_call

check_call([sys.executable or 'py', 'prov.py', r'D:\a.png'])
```